# Ajax not working with button

Tags: php, html, ajax, forms, submit

My Send button is not working. shouldnt the script take me to add.php ? 
but instead of it, it refresh the page? How and why? Help me out please
it was working without Ajax script.

Tommorow is my lab exam and i am unable to make the things work right.

What changes should i make in it to solve the problem.

```
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
<a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="index.php">Home</a>
<br/><br/>

<form method="post" id="form1">
    <table width="25%" border="0">
    ...
        ...
        <tr> 
            <td><input class="btn  btn-primary" type="reset" 
 name="Clear" value="Clear"></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="send" id="asdasd" 
 name="Submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e){
$("#form1").click(function() {

var name=$('#name').val();
var email=$('#email').val();
var age=$('#age').val();
var status=$('#status').val();

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '../crud/add2.php',
    data: $('#form1').serialize()
    });

});
});
</script>
```

here is my add.php file

```
<body>
<?php
//including the database connection file
include_once("config.php");

if(isset($_POST)) {
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['name']);
$age = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['age']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['email']);
$status = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['status']);

// checking empty fields
if(empty($name) || empty($age) || empty($email)|| empty($status)) {

    if(empty($name)) {
        echo "<font color='red'>Name field is empty.</font><br/>";
    }

    if(empty($age)) {
        echo "<font color='red'>Age field is empty.</font><br/>";
    }

    if(empty($email)) {
        echo "<font color='red'>Email field is empty.</font><br/>";
    }

    if(empty($status)) {
        echo "<font color='red'>Status field is empty.</font><br/>";
    }

    //link to the previous page
    echo "<br/><a href='javascript:self.history.back();'>Go Back</a>";
} else {
    // if all the fields are filled (not empty)

    //insert data to database
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO         
users(name,age,email,Status)         
VALUES('$name','$age','$email','$status')");

    //display success message
    echo "<font color='green'>Data added successfully.";
    echo "<br/><a href='index.php'>View Result</a>";
}
}
else {
echo "<font color='green'>NOOOOOOO added successfully.";
    echo "<br/><a href='index.php'>View Result</a>";
}  
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no redirect to add.php as far as i can see. You can add it after ajax returns output in order to get to add.php.

Comment: Also do you need to use ajax in your lab exam? Because if not, you can just put action iside form tag and set it to add.php

Comment: yes i need to use ajax. its my lab requirement, this requirement just posted today with few minutes before. "CRUD WITH AJAX"

Comment: i didnt get what do you want to say about redirecting . 
      url: '../crud/add2.php',
I did write in html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok as you said you need to use ajax in your lab exam here is how you redirect after ajax is done :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#asdasd").click(function(e) {

    var name=$('#name').val();
    var email=$('#email').val();
    var age=$('#age').val();
    var status=$('#status').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '../crud/add2.php',
            data: $('#form1').serialize()
        }).done(function(data){
            window.location.href = "add.php"; // or whatever redirect you want
        });

    });
});
</script>
```

Also im not sure if you understand that after redirect into the add.php you will not have $_POST data this way. Im not really sure why you want to redirect onto add.php in the fierst place because ajax will execute your script anywayt (though that is add2.php not add.php but i assume its just typo or something). You could instead append the output of ajax into the body of your current page (thats the essential use of ajax - no need for redirection). But if you want to add the data with ajax and also get POSTed data when redirecting yourself onto the add.php page, you would need something like this :

Change add action to form tag like this :

```
<form method="post" id="form1" action="add.php">
```

And then the script would look like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#asdasd").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name=$('#name').val();
    var email=$('#email').val();
    var age=$('#age').val();
    var status=$('#status').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '../crud/add2.php',
            data: $('#form1').serialize()
        }).done(function(data){
            $soap('#form1').submit();
        });

    });
});
</script>
```

But this way it would add the same row two times into your database.

**FINAL UPDATE:** 
Ok as you wanted in commencts add.php would look like this :

```
//including the database connection file
include_once("config.php");

if(isset($_POST)) {
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['name']);
    $age = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['age']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['email']);
    $status = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['status']);

    // checking empty fields
    $result = array();
    if(empty($name) || empty($age) || empty($email)|| empty($status)) {

        if(empty($name)) {
            $result['error']['name'] = 'Name field is empty.';
        }

        if(empty($age)) {
            $result['error']['age'] = 'Age field is empty.';
        }

        if(empty($email)) {
            $result['error']['email'] = 'Email field is empty.';
        }

        if(empty($status)) {
            $result['error']['status'] = 'Status field is empty.';
        }
    } else {
        // if all the fields are filled (not empty)

        //insert data to database
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO         
        users(name,age,email,Status)         
    VALUES('$name','$age','$email','$status')");

        //display success message
        $result['success'] = "<font color='green'>Data added successfully.".
        "<br/><a href='index.php'>View Result</a>";
    }
} else {
    $result['error_message'] = "<font color='green'>NOOOOOOO added successfully.".
    "<br/><a href='index.php'>View Result</a>";
}  
echo json_encode($result);
```

Script part:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#asdasd").click(function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '../crud/add.php',
            data: $('#form1').serialize(),
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function(data){
            if(data.hasOwnProperty('error_message')){
                $('#form1').after(data['error_message']);
            } else if(data.hasOwnProperty('error')){
                for(var key in data['error']) {
                    if (data['error'].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        $('#'+key).after(data['error'][key]);
                    }
                }
            } else if(data.hasOwnProperty('success')){
                $('#form1').after(data['success']);
            }
        });

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: let me try your way

Comment: I added some further info. Also it would be good if you told me if you really need to redirect after sending to data with ajax or just append some message after ajax is done.

Comment: my code is working like this

data obtained from html passes to -> add.php. after insertion query 
it echos with a home button.

Comment: i tried ur way. 
but it is only redirecting, data is not passing 
i guess the problem is with this
if(isset($_POST)) {

Comment: Yes thats why i was asking what you wanted to achieve. So after succesful INSERT into DB you just want to add home button right? So no redirection is needed. Or do you still want to redirect after insert anyway but post the same data again? Because i already edited answer that way.

Comment: i just want to insert my data through ajax.
before it . my application was on simple crud without ajax.

i am trying to convert it to ajax crud. 
but i am not fimilar with ajax syntax and its working. 

i only want to insert data. 
i hv a different add.php file
wouldnt i need a redirection ?
p.s EM NEWBIE

Comment: hey Redrif, 

Let me know two things 
what change should i make in add.php file
- when ever i click on anywhere in add.html . it just go to add.php

Comment: Hello i will edit my question so that you will not need to redirect and it will just add the info that the item was added into database. Because when you wont redirect onto add.php you dont even need to go back with back button right?

Answer (score 0):

Please create click event with button id, not a form id.. i have modified in your ajax script please try this script.

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(e){
       $("#asdasd").click(function() {
              var name=$('#name').val();
              var email=$('#email').val();
              var age=$('#age').val();
              var status=$('#status').val();

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: '../crud/add2.php',
           data: $('#form1').serialize()
      });

    });  
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function () {

 $('#form1').on('submit', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'add.php',
        data: $('#form1').serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            alert('form was submitted');



        },

    error: function () {
        alert('error');
    }
    });

});

});
```

both files .php .html must have a js file in which the above code is placed. 
this worked for me.